# Regex to replace everything except numbers greater than 4 characters long

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to replace all characters (including all whitespaces) in a string except for numbers greater than 4 characters in length, which should be separated by a comma.  I've been fussing with various scripts but none of them have been working:

I'm a newbie with Regex, so I was trying to use this function to get rid of pretty much everything else:

```
dataString.replace(/\s+/g,",").replace(/\t+/g,"").replace(/[,\s]{2,}/,"").replace(/^,*/,"").replace(/,*$/,"")
```

I was also thinking of using something along the lines of:

```
dataString.replace(^[0-9]{4+,}$)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: We're not going to write it for you. Show one of the versions you've fussed with, and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: :)  Well here's what I've been getting after (it's not what I need):

Comment: Don't try to put code in comments. Edit your question.

Comment: Do it the other way around. Instead of replacing everything that _isn't_ a 4+ digit number, use a regexp to match all the 4+ digit numbers and concatenate them into the result string.

Comment: ok, I'm not sure how to concatenate Regex matches using JavaScript

Comment: You don't know that `string1 + string2` concatenates strings?

Comment: But if I have n amount of numbers, do you just do this in a for() loop?  How do you have the Regex recognize each number and not the first one every time?

Comment: You have to determine what separates tokens in your string.  Usually a space, with the exception of the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = dataString.match(/\d{4,}/g).join(',');
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect!  Thanks!